# Cloudera cdh5.1.3 adding SPARK 0.9 using service wizard error SCALA_HOME is not set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am getting following error while adding Spark to CDH, for master and worker node configuration. I have followed the instructions in this link: https://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/Installing_Spark_and_Setting_Up_Your_Cluster

To set SCALA_HOME, it is giving me following error:

```
Service did not start successfully; not all of the required roles started: Service has only 0 Master roles running instead of minimum required 1.
Program: csd/csd.sh ["start_worker","./master.properties"]
Program: csd/csd.sh ["start_master","./master.properties"]

++ CDH_HADOOP_BIN=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop
++ export CDH_IMPALA_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/impala
++ CDH_IMPALA_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/impala
++ export CDH_SOLR_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/solr
++ CDH_SOLR_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/solr
++ export CDH_HBASE_INDEXER_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/hbase-solr
++ CDH_HBASE_INDEXER_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/hbase-solr
++ export SEARCH_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/search
++ SEARCH_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/search
++ export CDH_SPARK_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/spark
++ CDH_SPARK_HOME=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/spark
++ export WEBHCAT_DEFAULT_XML=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/etc/hive-webhcat/conf.dist/webhcat-default.xml
++ WEBHCAT_DEFAULT_XML=/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/etc/hive-webhcat/conf.dist/webhcat-default.xml
+ echo 'Using /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/751-spark-SPARK_MASTER as conf dir'
+ echo 'Using scripts/control.sh as process script'
+ chmod u+x /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/751-spark-SPARK_MASTER/scripts/control.sh
+ exec /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/751-spark-SPARK_MASTER/scripts/control.sh start_master ./master.properties
Thu Apr 16 09:44:51 GMT 2015
Thu Apr 16 09:44:51 GMT 2015: Detected CDH_VERSION of [5]
Thu Apr 16 09:44:51 GMT 2015: Found a master on syseng03 listening on port 7077
Thu Apr 16 09:44:51 GMT 2015: Starting Spark master on syseng03 and port 7077
/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/spark/bin/compute-classpath.sh: line 65: hadoop: command not found
SCALA_HOME is not set
```

Comment: Looks like its two step process -> 1)we need to install using parcels( download/distribute/install) and 2) then add service via wizard .. plz confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u clearly check log messages it says classpath is not set properly while installing spark using cloudera manager(as its expected from CM that it should resolve all dependencies automatically as I was installing from wizard but somehow it didn't worked)... 
  trick i did was to edit /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/spark/bin/compute-classpath.sh script and add all classpath info in it manually ...following lines I added "before" required classpath variables

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/bin
export SCALA_HOME=/app/scala-2.10.4
export SCALA_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/scala-2.10.4/lib
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/*"
```